# Pointwise convergence of average of continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Suppose that $(f^n)$ is a sequence of continuous functions from a compact metric space $A$ into a convex compact subset of the reals $B$. Is there a subsequence, $(f^{n_k})$, such that the sequence

$f^{n_1},(1/2)f^{n_1}+(1/2)f^{n_2},(1/3)f^{n_1}+(1/3)f^{n_2}+(1/3)f^{n_3},...$

converges pointwise to some map $f:A\to B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the sequence $(f^n)$.

Since the sequence $(f^n)$ is uniformly bounded, if it is equicontinuous then by [Arzelà–Ascoli theorem for compact Hausdorff spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem#Compact_metric_spaces_and_compact_Hausdorff_spaces), it is relatively compact in the space $C(A)$ of real-valued continuous functions on $A$. So it contains a subsequence $(f^{n_i})$, uniformly convergent to a function $f\in C(A)$. Then a sequence $\left(\frac 1k\sum_{i=1}^k f^{n_i}\right)$ uniformly converges to $f$ too.

But for general case the claim may fail. Consider the following example. Let $A$ be the Cantor cube, that is a countable power of a discrete space $\{0,1\}$ endowed with the Tychonoff product topology. For each $n$ let $f^n:A\to [0,1]$ be the projection at the $n$-th coordinate. Let $(n_i)$ be an arbitrary increasing sequence of natural numbers. It is easy to construct a set $D\subset\Bbb N$ with undefined density, that is such that the limit $d(D)=\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac 1k|\{ a\in D: a\le k\}|$ does not exist. Pick any point $x=(x_n)\in A$ such that for each natural $k$ we have $x_{n_k}=1$, if $k\in D$ and $x_{n_k}=0$, otherwise.  Since for each $k$ we have $|\{ a\in D: a\le k\}|=\sum_{i=1}^k f^{n_i}(x)$,  the limit $\frac 1k\sum_{i=1}^k f^{n_i}(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am little confused with the construction. Do you mean a set $D\subseteq\{0,1\}^N$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{k}(d_1+\dots+d_k)$ does not exist? And then pick $x\in A$ such that $x_{n_k}=d_k$ for each $k$?

Comment: @mo15 Oops, I sometimes denoted the set $D$ as $A$. Sorry. Corrected.

Comment: But $D$ must be a subset of $A$, not $N$, correct? An the limit $d(D)$ must be defined differently, I think.

Comment: In view of this example, a natural question would be whether the claim is true when $A$ is a compact subset of Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: No, $D$ is a subset of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: The claim depends not directly on $A$, but on the sequence. So it may fail, even when $A$ is a Cantor set, which is homeomorphic to a subset of $\Bbb R^1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86818/discussion-between-mo15-and-alex-ravsky).